# Correlation failed .NET 8

Tags: c#, google-oauth, blazor-webassembly, .net-8.0

> fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]       An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationFailureException: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationFailureException: Correlation failed.
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.HandleRequestAsync()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context).

I am using .NET 8 with Blazor webassembly

```
using DNAiWeb.Client.Pages;
using DNAiWeb.Components;
using MudBlazor.Services;
using DNAiBase.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using DNAiWeb.Components.Account;
using DNAiBase.Data;
using DNAiBase.Models;
using Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var services = builder.Services;
var configuration = builder.Configuration;


// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents()
    .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyComponents();


builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IdentityUserAccessor>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IdentityRedirectManager>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, IdentityRevalidatingAuthenticationStateProvider>();

/*builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
    //options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
}).AddCookie()
    .AddIdentityCookies();
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    
})
   
.AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
{
    googleOptions.ClientId = ""; // Replace with your Google client ID
    googleOptions.ClientSecret = ""; // Replace with your Google client secret
    googleOptions.CallbackPath = "/signin-google"; // Set the redirect URI
})
.AddCookie()
   .AddIdentityCookies(); 
*/
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; // Set Google as default challenge scheme
})
.AddCookie(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme) // Add cookie authentication with IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme
.AddCookie(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);
// Add cookie authentication with IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme
services.AddAuthentication()
.AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
{
    googleOptions.ClientId = "";
    googleOptions.ClientSecret = "";
    googleOptions.CallbackPath = "/signin-google";
});




/*builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
    //options.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie()
.AddIdentityCookies();

// Configure services for Google authentication
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddGoogle(options =>
    {
        options.ClientId = ""; // Replace with your Google client ID
        options.ClientSecret = ""; // Replace with your Google client secret
        options.CallbackPath = "/signin-google"; // Set the redirect URI
    }); 

*/


var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("postgresConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseNpgsql(connectionString, b => b.MigrationsAssembly("DNAiWeb")));

builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddSignInManager()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IEmailSender<ApplicationUser>, IdentityNoOpEmailSender>();

builder.Services.AddMudServices();
builder.Services.AddScoped<UserScopedService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<DNAiOpenAI>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseAntiforgery();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseMiddleware<BlazorCookieLoginMiddleware>();

app.MapAdditionalIdentityEndpoints();

app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode()
    .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode()
    .AddAdditionalAssemblies(typeof(Counter).Assembly);
app.MapGet("/signin-google", () => new GoogleAuthController());

app.Run();
```

Kindly check what causes the problem. Both the authentication works without one another. There is problem with integration